# NoSuchMethodError when using Spark and IntelliJ

Tags: scala, apache-spark, intellij-idea, jvm

I'm new to Scala and Spark. I've been frustrated by how hard it has been to get things to work with IntelliJ. Currently, I can't get run the code below. I'm sure it's something simple, but I can't get it to work.

I'm trying to run:

```
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}

object TestScala {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val conf = new SparkConf()
    conf.setAppName("Datasets Test")
    conf.setMaster("local[2]")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
    println(sc)
  }
}
```

The error I get is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.Predef$.refArrayOps([Ljava/lang/Object;)Lscala/collection/mutable/ArrayOps;
at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.getCallSite(Utils.scala:1413)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:77)
at TestScala$.main(TestScala.scala:13)
at TestScala.main(TestScala.scala)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
```

My build.sbt file:

```
name := "sparkBook"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.12.1"
```

Comment: I am here to help, Don't get frustrated. Show me your `build.sbt` ?

Comment: How are you running it? What kind of project have you set it up as? How does your `build.sbt` look like? Literally, it didn't take more than a minute for me to create a new project, copy your code, change the print statement to `println("AppName: " + sc.appName)`, run it, and see the expected output - which is `AppName: Datasets Test`.

Comment: @YoungSpice I figured out what I was doing wrong. Fixed that; now get different error. Changed my post. Running it as a scala script.

Comment: @pamu I get different error now. It doesn't recognize a method. Added sbt build file.

Comment: @lars your `build.sbt` does not contain spark dependencies. why ?

Comment: @lars right way is 1) open intellij 2) create new sbt project 3) go to `build.sbt` and add apache spark as dependency and then 4) write a main method with your code 5) run using `sbt run`

Comment: I'm following (https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/files/basic/anonymous/api/library/e5c0146d-f723-446b-9151-c31d4c56ed01/document/b41505ac-141b-45a2-84cd-1b6a8d5ae653/media/Setting%20up%20spark%202.0%20with%20intellij%20community%20edition.pdf

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75947449/run-a-scala-code-jar-appear-nosuchmethoderrorscala-predef-refarrayops

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change your `scalaVersion` to `2.11.8` and add the Spark dependency to your `build.sbt`:

`libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.11" % "2.0.2"`

Comment: It's a bit more idiomatic to use `libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.0.2"` isn't it?

Comment: @AngeloGenovese You're right, it is more idiomatic but I was a bit hesitant to suggest that because if the Scala version is changed to 2.12, the build would fail if Spark hasn't been published for that version. At least from what I've seen, this situation hasn't been easy to debug if the developer isn't aware of the `%%` vs `%` semantics.

Comment: Yeah maybe, but then I run into even a bigger problem with this weird error: https://github.com/sbt/zinc/issues/276 where the "compiler-bridge_2.11" package could not be compiled. Scala 2.11.0, 2.11.8, 2.11.11 did not work, but 2.11.12 worked!

Answer (score 2):

One more scenario is intellij is pointing to 2.12.4 and all the maven/sbt dependencies are 2.11.8. with scala dep verion 2.11...

I stepped back from 2.12.4 to 2.11.8 at global libraries of intellij ui. and it started working

***Details :***

Maven pom.xml pointing to 2.11.8 But in my Intellij... sdk is  2.12.4 in global libraries shown below.
Which is causing

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.Predef$.refArrayOps([Ljava/lang/Object;)Lscala/collection/mutable/ArrayOps;
```

[image]
Stepped back to 2.11.8 in Global libraries.. like below

[image]
Thats it.. Problem solved. No more error for executing that program.

> ***Conclusion :*** Maven dependencies alone should not solve the problem, along with that we have to configure scala sdk in global
>   libraries since its error is coming while running a spark local
>   program and error is related to Intellij run time.

Answer (score 0):

If you use spark 2.4.3, you need to use scala 2.11 even though spark website says to use scala 2.12. https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/

To avoid `scala.Predef$.refArrayOps([Ljava/lang/Object;)[Ljava/lang/Object;`

Comment: how can I use scale 2.12 ?