# SBT dependency error for Scala Spark on Intellij

Tags: scala, apache-spark, intellij-idea, sbt

I am a noob to Spark and Intellij.I want to run Spark using Scala
I initially installed Scala 2.12 and created the SBT accordingly.Then I got a NoSuchMethod runtime error on

```
       sc =  new SparkContext(conf)
```

From the solution posted [NoSuchMethodError when using Sparka and IntelliJ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41109395/nosuchmethoderror-when-using-sparka-and-intellij) I used Scala version 2.11.3 while creating the project and used the SBT

```
version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.11.3"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.11" % "2.0.2"
```

I am now getting the error

```
   Error:scalac: No 'scala-library*.jar' in Scala compiler classpath in Scala SDK SBT: org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.11.3:jar
```

This is the library on the External libraries section [image: Snapshot from Project External Libraries]

I tried creating the project from scratch and Cache Invalidate/Restart option.Same result

I also tried downloading via Maven through File -> Project Structure.Only found spark-core 2.10.Showed the same NoSuchMethod Error

Can anyone identify the problem?

Comment: can you see  scala-compiler.jar, scala-library.jar, scala-reflect.jar libraries in Project Structure -> modules ?

Comment: Thanks @Shankar Koirala.I could not see them before but I just uninstalled scala plugin and restarted and reinstalled and it worked.It was just magic..:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It clearly says that, It could not find scala-library*.jar file

So go to

```
"Project Structure -> Modules"
```

And see these jar files

```
scala-compiler.jar, scala-library.jar, scala-reflect.jar
```

If they are absent from the Modules add them manually or Reinstall the scala and scala plugin.

Hope this should work!